# Are there initializing snapshots to include all order IDs in LOBSTER sample data?

Tags: limit-order-book

I've implemented a L2 order book handler based on the classic [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110219163448/http://howtohft.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/how-to-build-a-fast-limit-order-book/) I'm sure everyone has come across when researching this topic!

I've used the message files from LOBSTER sample data as input and formatted my output to match the LOBSTER order book files in order to check my work.

After a few hundred lines of the message file are parsed, my checks fail: upon investigation, I noticed that this is due to cancellation or execution messages for order IDs that do not have corresponding entry messages prior in the message file. I.E. we are trying to cancel / execute orders that do not exist in our order book.

I know this will be due to the fact that these orders will have been submitted in an earlier session and that data simply isn't included in the sample - my question is how do can we initialize the book to include these order IDs or do they exist in the sample data at all?

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a better *free* data set to use let me know (I know there are free ITCH samples, but wanted to start with something simpler first), cheers!